# Can I attach a JS script as text in an email?

Tags: javascript, email

In the sent e-mail I would like to attach a code fragment in JS to be copied by the recipient?

It should be plain text to be copied only.

There is simply no such possibility. The question is, is it possible to do it some other way?

Comment: Yes. Plain text or Zip it....

Comment: *"There is simply no such possibility."* JavaScript code is text, emails are text. You can just copy and paste the code into your email.

Comment: @FelixKling I send the e-mail via `MailKit` from the application and when I add it as text, it cuts this whole part out for me. I added in `<pre>` and `<code>` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is MailKit? Perhaps you should add the code you're using to send the email then instead of talking about theoreticals about whether something is possible.